# repeat several trigger('click') functions every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 links. I want (unreal) click it via jquery every 2 second until I click (real click) on a link.

I try do it with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var itabs = ["a1", "a2", "a3", , "a4"];
    i = 0;
    while(true) {
        $("#" + itabs[i]).delay(2000).trigger('click');
        i++;
        if(i > 3) i = 0;
        //if(real click on a1 or a2 or a3 or a4) break;
    }
});
```

But it only works once for `i=0`;

and I want to know how can I add a condition to check real click and then runs `break`;

Comment: Use `setInterval`. **Answer:** `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var itabs = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#' + itabs[i++]).trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
});`

Comment: thanks but it runs only once, like my code.

Comment: @Tushar is there any reason that you posted your answer as a comment? This is not how StackOverflow is supposed to work, you know. Also, see these Meta threads: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I do that when I feel lazy to post it as answer and explain or when I'm not sure if that'll work.

Comment: @Tushar that's a bad excuse

Answer (score 2):

setInterval() will do what you are looking for. Here is an example of a click being triggered every second until it's been triggered 4 times.

https://jsfiddle.net/69d8771x/3/

```
   var numclicks = 0;
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(event, triggeredmanually) {
    if(triggeredmanually)
        alert('click fake');
    else
        alert('click real');
});

var intervalid = setInterval(function() {
    $('#mybutton').trigger('click', [true]); 
    numclicks++; 

    if(numclicks == 2) {
     clearInterval(intervalid);
        alert('done');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks it works for alert but runs once for trigger('click')

Comment: No, it triggers the click 4 times. if you look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/69d8771x/2/ you will see an alert every time the click is triggered and then one when it has hit the numclicks condition.

Comment: @Tushar : I think I understand now. He is saying that I was missing the part to differentiate the manually triggered/real click events. I updated the code

Comment: So he changed his original question to include 3 links after I explained to him what to do? I'm out

Comment: @jnoreiga thanks. your code works normally but not for trigger. please check this demo. https://jsfiddle.net/whjy5yq0/2/

Comment: That because your original question didn't have multiple links. You asked about 1 link. But good luck anyway.

Comment: @jnoreiga I do not agree with u. `var itabs = ["a1", "a2", "a3", , "a4"];` it is clear I have 4 ids. anyway thanks for the answer,

Answer (score 2):

Use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

The function that is passed to the `setInterval` is called repeatedly after duration passed as second parameter.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1fvqvjb3/)

```
var interval;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var itabs = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"],
        arrLen = itabs.length,
        i = 0;

    // Use interval of 2 seconds
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        // Show the respective element
        $($('#' + itabs[i++ % arrLen]).attr('href')).show().siblings('p').hide();
    }, 2000);

    $('a').on('click', function () {
        // Cleare interval
        clearInterval(interval);

        // Show corresponding element
        $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('p').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks I create a live demo for the code: https://jsfiddle.net/whjy5yq0/3/  it does not work, (only when  I use trigger('click'))

Comment: @partiz Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1fvqvjb3/). Ignore the CSS styles.

Comment: thanks. I want only use trigger click. not show and hide function.